# Reduce as many adjacent chars as possible in string

Tags: python, performance, strings, programming-challenge, python-3.x

This code is meant to reduce a given string as much as possible by deleting adjacent characters. Here are some examples:

```
reduce('aa') = 'Empty String'
reduce('ab') = 'ab'
reduce('abba') = 'Empty String' # remove 'bb' then 'aa'
reduce('bbb') = 'b'  # can only delete 2 chars at a time
```

This is based off [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string) HackerRank question.

I'm doing this to improve my style and to improve my knowledge of fundamental algorithms/data structures for an upcoming coding interview.

```
def reduce(s):
    cur_chars = list(s)
    while cur_chars:
        new_chars = do_deletions(cur_chars)
        if new_chars == cur_chars:  # if nothing deleted then return
            new_s = ''.join(cur_chars)
            return new_s
        else:
            cur_chars = new_chars  # do another round of deletions
    return 'Empty String'


def do_deletions(org_chars):
    if len(org_chars) == 1:
        return org_chars

    new_chars = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(org_chars):
        if i == len(org_chars) - 1:
            new_chars.append(org_chars[i])
            i += 1
        elif org_chars[i] == org_chars[i+1]:
            i += 2  # don't include char i and i+1
        elif org_chars[i] != org_chars[i+1]:
            new_chars.append(org_chars[i])
            i += 1
    return new_chars
```

I was originally going to do deletions using 2 consecutive `del` commands (`O(n)`) but then I thought this performance would be too bad for an interview. Instead I opted to not do any deletions and just use appends to create gradually reduced strings. If my original approach would have been fine for an interview then let me know.

I think this algorithm is `O(n^2)` time and `O(n)` space. Any suggestions about how I can improve the complexities are welcome.

Comment: Should `'bbb'` be reduced to the empty string as well?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger It should return just `'b'` since you can only delete 2 characters at a time. I should have made that clearer in the question. I'll edit it to make it clear.

Answer (score 10):

This is related to the task of checking for matching parentheses. You can solve it in a single pass if you compare the current `org_char` to the latest `new_char`, and if they are the same, remove the latest `new_char` and skip the current `org_char`.

The `do_deletions` function already defines the `org_chars` and the `new_chars`. Instead of comparing only the `org_chars`, you should check whether `len(new_chars) > 0 and org_chars[i] == new_chars[-1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give an example or elaborate a bit more on what you mean?

Comment: Ok. It makes more sense now. Thanks again for the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

About the Algorithms:

How can your be improved:

- Lets take an example: reduce ('abba');

Current algorithm:

```
do_delete('a') would return 'a'
do_delete('ab') would return 'ab'
do_delete('abb') would return 'a'
do_delete('abba') would return ''
```

Change the argument to accept the new_chars + the new letter and compare just 'i' with 'i-1';

```
  do_delete('a') would return 'a'
  do_delete('ab') would compare 'b' with 'a'  and return 'ab'
  do_delete('abb') would compare 'b' with 'b' and return 'a'
  do_delete('aa') would compare 'a' with 'a' and return
```

Benefits: O(1) comparison.

Elaborating Roland's answer: You can use a STACK {Complexity: Time O(n), Space O(n)}.

- Suppose the input is "abbccaa".
- Take a letter, check the top of the stack. If it matches, pop the top and ignore the letter.
- If the letter doesn't match the top of the stack, push the letter and continue.
- After the array traversal completes, check the stack. If its empty, return "Empty string" else return the reversed string formed by concatenation of values in the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for elaborating a bit more on Roland's answer. I like how you provided the complexities for the new approach.

Comment: You don't really need a separate stack, do you?  You can use the output buffer (or the end-of-result position if you modify a buffer in-place) as a stack.  It's slightly more complicated if a run of 3 or more chars should still be eliminated, rather than just removing matching pairs.  Since then you can't forget about what you've already seen after seeing a pair.  (Oh, but I see that's not the case, `bbb` => `b`.)

Comment: With your algorithm, you don't need a stack. With the new algorithm, you can use a stack.